# What's the historical development of ahadith book of Bukhari?

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari

What's the historical development of ahadith book of Bukhari ?

Are we sure that the version we have today is the same as the first version?

[Original Copies of Muhammad al-Bukhari's Books?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/original-copies-of-muhammad-al-bukharis-books) <- This question has a wrong answer. Thus, I'm keeping my question.

Comment: The original version is lost, so we can't really determine if it's the same.

Comment: Why would you make such a claim without any reference, @Sayyid ? Whose opinion do you accept when you say the original is lost when there's Ijma of Ulama that Bukhari is one of the most authentic Hadith books.

Comment: So, where's the original?

Comment: That's what I am asking :) Maybe someone knows.

Comment: Maybe @Sorrel Vesper has it, since he alleged a consensus.  As far as I've seen, the original copy was long lost hundreds of years ago.  What we have today is merely a collection from different sources.  Even the earlier work, Muwattta Malik, has two different versions in circulation and we don't even know which one is neartest to the original since that's lost too.

Comment: @Sayyid which 2 Versions of Muwatta' you mean? I mean there should be at least hundreds as any student who had  got his copy confirmed by Malik would have one. As Malik Muwatta' was a work in progress so later copies may have less narrations because Malik revised them or revised his qualification of some narrations! Therefore there's a consensus to define that the Muwatta' copy of Yahya ibn Yahya al-Laithi is the (final) Muwatta'

Comment: @SorrelVesper That question has no answer.

Comment: If this is the standard for you that original hand written book should be present to prove that this is original text, than not even Quran can be said authentic, nauzubillah. And i don't think any religious bok this old would have any original scriptures left anyway, illa ma sha Allah.

Comment: As @ZiaUlRehmanMughal said the original doesn't need to exist anymore. As hadith was also kept due to memorization, as books were very expensive. Still today people memorize ahadith with the full sanad. I know about temporary scholars who had a continuous sanad until Imam a-Nawawi. And quran has been kept the same way some hafiz have a continuous narrator chain til the Prophet (pbuh) in one of the qiraat so the shortest would have at least 27 narrators between them and the Prophet (pbuh).

Comment: Also relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/can-any-hadith-truly-be-called-sahih-anymore. Are you more interested in knowing how sahih al-Bukhari has been collected and compiled or in the matter of my linked relevant question. If there's any evidence to show that the copy we now hold in hand is the same al-Bukhari may have compiled or dictated?

Comment: @Medi1Saif The latter one.

Comment: Then this answer is what you are looking for http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5360/13438 and your question should be a duplicate, as this is exactly what goldenPseudo wanted to know as far as i understood from our chat on this topic.